# What are the cheapest flight schools for a PPL license ($12500)?

Tags: flight-training, ppl, cost, flight-school

I live in Egypt and I finally decided to pursue my dream to become a pilot. The first step as everybody surely knows is to get my PPL license. However, in order for me a NON-US citizen to be eligible for the training in any flight school in the US I need to submit an application on the TSA website to be approved for receiving flight training. The thing is, in order for me to apply, I need to specify a flight school (it is not a general permit, it needs to be directed towards a specific flight school). For my PPL, I have saved the average amount (based on my research on the average cost to become a PPL) of $12,500 excluding ground school fees. The issue is that there are a TON of flight schools in the US and I have no clue as to where to even start to narrow down a list of schools that will fall within the limit of my budget. I am open to train in any state in the US. What I need is the names of some schools that will fall into the budget so I can research them and select one.

Thanks for your time reading this...

Comment: Learning to fly is very expensive.  Flying after you get your licence is also very expensive...